# What does "not yet see" mean in Hebrews 2:8?

Tags: word-study, hebrews

"Now in putting everything in subjection to him, he left nothing outside his control. At present, we do not yet see everything in subjection to him." E.S.V.

Possible considerations:

1. Is "not yet see" a comment on what was the situation, or, ability to see the situation?
2. Romans 8:24 "For who hopes for what he sees". We hope "he left nothing outside his control" is true. Do we get glimpses, or, is that hope as oppose to seeing?
3. What is not yet seen?

Comment: Romans 8:18:19 at a minimum shows two things not yet fully subjected to him. Our mortal bodies (which will be replaced with glorified bodies) and nature which is subjected to corruption because the lamb does not yet lie down with the lion. Hence why there will have to be a new heaven and a new earth.

Comment: @Nihil Sine Deo Why would our having or not having a particular body not be subject to God's timing?

Comment: “Wretched man that I am! Who will deliver me from this body of death? Thanks be to God through Jesus Christ our Lord! So then, I myself serve the law of God with my mind, but with my flesh I serve the law of sin.”
‭‭Rom7:24-25‬ ‭Because God cannot accept anything that is of the corrupted sinful flesh. Nothing done of the flesh by the flesh is acceptable before God. It’s putrid rags. “For I know that nothing good dwells in me, that is, in my flesh. For I have the desire to do what is right, but not the ability to carry it out.”
‭‭Rom‭7:18‬ ‭He couldn’t do it even if he tried. It’s corrupted.

Comment: @Nihil Sine Deo God gives commands but is it His will that we obey them? "Yes" if He gives us the grace to obey and "No" if He does not give us the grace to obey. God could not make us as Himself because He is unmade. He has a holy motive in making us dependent upon Himself and His grace and demonstrating this as in Adam's sin. Do you agree?

Comment: I’m not sure I agree because I don’t understand what your wrote just yet. Anything that is authored... has its origin... is initiated... is concocted by the FLESH cannot and will not be received by God. God offers to indwell our bodies as a Spirit, communicating with our (born again) spirit and influencing our soul (mind, will, emotions) to act on our bodies. But if our flesh tries to do the exact same thing without the Spirit’s leading it is not acceptable. It must come from God who sanctified our mortal bodies.

Comment: @Nihil Sine Deo In Romans 9. 21-23 God makes different sorts of vessels/people, some to make known His wrath and some to make known His mercy. Here human destiny is up to Him not us. The appearance is that our destiny is up to us is because we have instrumental responsibility for our actions but ultimate responsibility, why we do what we do, is up to God, all things have been subjected to Him.

Comment: we don’t agree. You seem to have a Calvinist (extraBiblical gnostic) view point which I can’t reconcile with Scripture even if you are quoting from Scripture. If you think that you don’t have free will then we most certainly disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'...You have subjected all things under His feet.' For in subjecting all things to Him, He left nothing unsubject to Him. But now we do not yet see all things subjected to Him. Heb 2:8. For You have caused Him to rule over the works of Your hands; You have put all things under His feet. **Psa 8:6**.

What's not yet seen is the next age: the 1000-year direct physical rule of Christ with His overcomers, on (the old) earth, over the sheep of **Mt 25:31-46. Rv 2:26-27; 12:5, 11; 20:1-7**.

For it was not to angels that He subjected **the coming inhabited earth, concerning which we speak**. Heb 2:5.

And when He brings again the Firstborn **into the inhabited earth**, He says, 'And let all the angels of God worship Him.' 1:6. 'Sit at My right hand **until I set** Your enemies as a footstool for Your feet'? 1:13.

For if Joshua had brought them into rest, He would not have spoken concerning another day after these things. So then **there remains a Sabbath rest** for the people of God. 4:8-9.

Christ also, having been offered once to bear the sins of many, **will appear a second time** to those who eagerly await Him, apart from sin, unto salvation. 9:28.

This One, having offered one sacrifice for sins, sat down forever on the right hand of God, henceforth waiting **until His enemies are made the footstool for His feet**. 10:12-13. Exhorting one another; and so much the more as you see **the day drawing near**. 10:25. **[G]reat reward**. For you have need of endurance in order that, having done the will of God, you may **obtain the promise**. 'For in yet a very little while **the Coming One will come** and will not delay.' 10:35-37.

Comment: Are there not two sorts of things unseen. 1. Those that have not occurred because their time has not yet come. 2. There are truths which right now we can apprehend only through faith and not by sight.e.g. would not sight deny that all things are in subjection to him as this verse affirms. The righteous shall live by faith.

Comment: Right...I have hope (Titus 2:13) that the physical kingdom of the Son of Man, the Son of David, will come. And faith that He is God, Christ, and Ruler over everyone and everything now (Rv 1:5-6; Ac 2:36). And need to believe into Him daily, more, to the 'gaining of my soul,' Heb 10:39; 11:27.